# How i can over write permission for special channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I need to overwrite permissions for a piece of time

For example:

```js
message.channel.send('you don\'t has permission to send message');
// (overwrite send message permission to false for x role)
// 5min time out later
// (overwrite send message permission to true for X role)
```

Person: !block all

Another person: you don't have permission to send message

5 min later

another person: *write normally*

How I can do this.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Channel.updatePermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannelscrollTo=updateOverwrite) and the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function.

```js
// `updateOverwrites()` accepts a user or role id
// I'm using `message.guild.id` because, fun fact,
// the @everyone role shares the same id as the guild its in
function lockChannel(bool) {
  message.channel.updateOverwrites(message.guild.id, 
    {
       SEND_MESSAGES: !bool, // update their send messages permission
    },
  );
}

// lock channel
lockChannel(true);

// wait five minutes and unlock it
setTimeout(() => lockChannel(false), 300000);
```